# Communication between Windows Form Application and Web Page in C#

Tags: c#, .net, web, desktop-application

I am developing a windows based application using C#.

This should be used by the customer after some verification. 
Every time they enter the details, the information should be validated in the server. And based on the response the windows-application should proceed further.

Could you please suggest me some examples or technologies ideal for this scenario?

I read through the documentations about WebClient and HttpWebRequest. But still I am not clear. Sorry I am an Embedded Systems Programmer. I haven't worked on Server related technologies.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a webservice would be a good solution.

look here for more information on creating a webservice:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/myservice.aspx

then you can import your webservice like a reference to a class and use it in your clientside c# programm.

http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=15
this article is for VB, but it shouldn't be a problem, the important thing is the referencing, which is Visual Studio specific and not VB specific.

Comment: Better to use Windows Communication Foundation, not obsolete ASP.NET asmx web services.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324) it is a service and messaging framework designed for exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at a WCF service using a NetTcpBinding. Here is a good link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163394.aspx

I am a little unsure what your reference to a web page in the post title refers to.